# Проблема с XMLHttpRequest(), не всегда получается прочесть содержимое текстового файла

Tags: javascript

**Есть функция, которая должна вернуть текст из файла**

```
//Функция возращает текст из файла nameTextFile 
function fileProcess() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', nameTextFile, true);
   xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState != 4) return;
        // по окончании запроса доступны: // status, statusText  // responseText, responseXML (при content-type: text/xml)
        if (this.status != 200) {
            // обработать ошибку
            alert('ошибка: ' + (this.status ? this.statusText : 'запрос не удался'));
            return;        }
        // получить результат из this.responseText или this.responseXML
    }
        //alert('готово');
    DataFirm = (xhr.responseText);
    return DataFirm;;
    }
```

Так вот, возвращается пусто, а вот если включить alert перед строкой responseText  то все нормально возращается. В чем может быть причина? я так понимаю всё дело в том, что alert останавливает код и ждет нажатия ОК, в это время все что, нужно подгружается. Но alert мне совсем не нужен, прям никак.

Comment: так возврат у вас синхронный, а требуется асинхронный. См. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

Comment: `true` поменяйте на `false` в `open()`.

Comment: Согласно http://xmlhttprequest.ru/ у меня как раз асинхронный (TRUE), синхронный (false) вроде как не советуют. Или я неправильно все понял? переключил на false и заработало.

Comment: @NykolayRyzhov, запрос у вас асинхронный, но ответ вы получаете синхронно! По этой причине данные от сервера не успевают приходить в переменную. Либо сделайте запрос синхронным, либо ответ получайте асинхронно.

Comment: В вопросе разобрался, может кому полезно будет, действительно когда асинхронный запрос, программа не дожидаясь ответа продолжает идти своим путем и если к этому времени переменная не получила данные из файла, будут извлечены по умолчанию. При этом самое плохое, что если ответ приходит вовремя, то кажется, что все нормально работает до тех пор пока не произойдет задержка. Правильно будет не передавать данный в глобальную переменную, а вызывать последующие действия из этой подпрограммы. Хотя это опять же мы переводим вызов в синхронный режим.